# One-side margins in Memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, single-sided

University requirements stipulate that the margins for the thesis be 3.5cms all around and 4 cms on the left. I used the following code but the **even-page margins** seem to be off. How can make the document have the same margin dimensions as the first image (odd-page):

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Odd Page Margins]

[image: Even Page Margins]

Comment: `memoir` make page layout correct, but `showframe` doesn't show them correctly.

Comment: You, sir, are absolutely right!, Just checked the alignment, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As Zarko's comment points out, there's something wrong with the way `showframe` is framing the page.

Try replacing this:

```
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
```

with this:

```
\pagestyle{showlocs}
```

and you should get correct framing; the `showlocs` page style is described in the Memoir manual, section 7.4.

Comment: Hi Brent; apologies for commenting on an answer for this, but I wasn't sure how else to get hold of you. I've commented upon  an issue on your GitHub, and haven't heard anything. Just wondered if you have a preferred method of communication?

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, sorry, I'm taking a bit of a holiday from github. I hope to write to you soon.